# #pragma link for template function

Tags: c++, templates, pragma, cling

I use cling and would like to see my templates function into environment, so after loading (.L)  of my class I want to be able to call my template function.

I can do this for such template:

```
template <typename T>
    static void ObjectApplyStyle(const char* styleName, T *cObj, Int_t objNum=0, Int_t verbose=0);
```

For such function I added in my LinkDef.h file next strings:

```
#pragma link C++ function AliDrawStyle::ObjectApplyStyle(const char*, TGraph *, Int_t, Int_t);
#pragma link C++ function AliDrawStyle::ObjectApplyStyle(const char*, TH1 *, Int_t, Int_t);
#pragma link C++ function AliDrawStyle::ObjectApplyStyle(const char*, TF1 *, Int_t, Int_t);
```

So my question is how I can do the same, but for such template function?

```
  template <typename T>
    static T PrepareValue(const char* styleName, TString propertyName, TString elementID, TString classID, TString objectID, TString localStyle, Bool_t &status, Int_t objNum=0, Int_t verbose=0);
```

If I will add this string in LinkDef.h:

```
#pragma link C++ function <Int_t> AliDrawStyle::PrepareValue(const char*, TString, TString, TString, TString, TString, Bool_t &, Int_t, Int_t);
#pragma link C++ function <Float_t> AliDrawStyle::PrepareValue(const char*, TString, TString, TString, TString, TString, Bool_t &, Int_t, Int_t);
```

compiler give me warning "func not found".

As you can see here  the difference between my templates functions - the first contain T type in arguments, but the second has the same arguments list and has a different type of returned value.

Do you have any idea?

*In Addition to discussion with Axel:*

Let's see to examples:

**MyClass.h**

```
class MyClass {

    public:
        template <typename T>
            static T Ex1();
        template <typename T>
            static T Ex2();

};
```

**MyClass.cxx**

```
#include "MyClass.h"

template <typename T>
    T MyClass::Ex1(){

}

template <typename T>
    T MyClass::Ex2(){
}
```

And this what I see in root6:

```
root [0] #include "MyClass.h"
root [1] MyClass::
MyClass
operator=
~MyClass
root [1] MyClass::
```

And the same for .L

```
root [0] .L MyClass.cxx+ 
root [1] MyClass::
MyClass
operator=
~MyClass
root [1] MyClass::
```

But if I add explicit calling for one function:
**MyClass.cxx**

```
#include "MyClass.h"

template <typename T>
    T MyClass::Ex1(){
      // here I added calling of template function
      MyClass::Ex2<float>();

}

template <typename T>
    T MyClass::Ex2(){
}
```

I will start to see:

```
root [0] .L MyClass.cxx+ 
root [1] MyClass::
Ex2<float>
MyClass
operator=
~MyClass
root [1] .q
```

But if I will use only include I can't see my function anycase:

```
root [0] #include "MyClass.h"
root [1] MyClass::
MyClass
operator=
~MyClass
```

Thanks!

Comment: For cling my question doesn't have a sense. only one thing is needed in order to add your function into environment. It should be use in your code, in this case your function will be automatically add.

But in this case question still open, because how can I do the same thing for cint now?

Comment: In linkdef you should add this strings for my case:

#pragma link C++ function AliDrawStyle::PrepareValue<Int_t>;
#pragma link C++ function AliDrawStyle::PrepareValue<Float_t>;

Answer (score 0):

No need for adding your function to a LinkDef.h. Just `#include` the header (or `.L` your class) and call it! If that fails please post the error message.

Comment: Axel, thank you for your response.

Hmm...sorry, but I did not quite understand what did you mean.
So, I have my class with interface (.h) and implementation(.cxx), and in my header file I have definition of template static function and in .cxx I have implementation of it, what should I add to #include?

Comment: Cling doesn't use `Linkdef.h` files. At the cling prompt, do `#include "MyClass.h"` and you will be able to call any functions, even specializations of template functions. To make progress we need to know what you type (exactly, as in copy&paster) and what you get as error messages (exactly, as in copy&paste).